# Looping through arrays and adding by index to another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, rotation, transpose

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array(8) {
  ["rentalPropertyAddress"]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "111 tree st"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "112 tree st"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "122 tree st"
  }
  ["gasInitialized"]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "on"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "on"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "off"
  }
  ["waterInitialized"]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "off"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "on"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "on"
  }
  ["electricInitialized"]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "on"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "on"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "off"
  }
  ["inspectionDate"]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["rentalDate"]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["vacantInitialized"]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "no"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "no"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "yes"
  }
}
```

What I need to do is add each index of each array into another array or array's. For example expected output would be:

```
array {
  array {
    [0] => string(11) "111 tree st"
    [1] => string(2) "on"
    [2] => string(3) "off"
    [3] => string(2) "on"
    [4] => string(0) ""
    [5] => string(0) ""
    [6] => string(2) "no"
  }
  ...
}
```

I've tried doing this with a forloop by looping through the array and keeping and index of it:

```
$i = -1;
$retval = array();
foreach ($_GET as $key => $item) {
    $i += 1;
    $retval[$i] = $item[$i];
}
echo "<pre>";var_dump($retval);
```

But the output is not what Im expecting:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "111 tree st"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "on"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "on"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "off"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```

How can I successfully extract the data out of the array into different arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I don't misunderstood your required output** then you can use **two** `foreach()` to iterate every nested array and push every element by their index position of all nested array.

```
   $_GET = [
         "rentalPropertyAddress"=>["111 tree st","112 tree st","122 tree st"],
         "gasInitialized"=>["on","on","off"],
         "waterInitialized"=>["off","on","on"],
         "electricInitialized"=>["on","on","off"],
         "inspectionDate"=>["","",""],
         "rentalDate"=>["","",""],
         "vacantInitialized"=>["no","no","yes"]
];

$retval = [];
foreach ($_GET as $key => $item) {
    $i=0;
    foreach($item as $k=>$v){
      $retval[$i][] = $v;
      $i++;
    }  
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($retval);
echo "</pre>";
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/LrpGo

Comment: Yes something like that, but I need to do it for every index in the array, forgive me for my wording im not a php dev

Comment: Yes, but it is doing for every index by key=>value way.  Let me know If I miss something..Have a try on my example code and lets see what is the output?

Comment: Yes it does exactly what you're saying. But it only does it for the first index: `array(7) {
  ["rentalPropertyAddress"]=>
  string(11) "111 tree st"
  ["gasInitialized"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["waterInitialized"]=>
  string(3) "off"
  ["electricInitialized"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["inspectionDate"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["rentalDate"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["vacantInitialized"]=>
  string(2) "no"
}`

Comment: @saladCracker Ohh, my bad I got your expected output now. See my **EDIT**. Hope it will work for all index now :)

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for switching columns to rows is:

```
foreach ($a as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
        $result[$col][] = $value;
    }
}
```

However, you may be able to get this result in the superglobal without needing to transform it with PHP by renaming your form inputs (assuming the data is coming from a form) from something like

```
<input type="text" name="rentalPropertyAddress[]">
<input type="text" name="rentalPropertyAddress[]">
```

to this format

```
<input type="text" name="properties[0][rentalPropertyAddress]">
<input type="text" name="properties[1][rentalPropertyAddress]">
```

This should still be possible, even if you are dynamically adding rows with JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wearing socks, you may want to hang onto them.  The technique that you are seeking is called "array transposing".  So long as you remove the outer associative keys, `array_map()` and a splat operator (`...`) will quickly prepare your data.

```
var_export(array_map(null,...array_values($_GET)));
```

Yes, it really is **THAT** easy. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/YIZq9)

The only way it gets easier than this is if you follow Don'tPanic's advice and prepare your data structure back at the html form.

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '111 tree st',
    1 => 'on',
    2 => 'off',
    3 => 'on',
    4 => '',
    5 => '',
    6 => 'no',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '112 tree st',
    1 => 'on',
    2 => 'on',
    3 => 'on',
    4 => '',
    5 => '',
    6 => 'no',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '122 tree st',
    1 => 'off',
    2 => 'on',
    3 => 'off',
    4 => '',
    5 => '',
    6 => 'yes',
  ),
)
```

Comment: ugh... just realized that splash already commented this.  Now I don't feel nearly as cool.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest doing the following for those running a php version from 7.1 up to 7.3 (see demo link for example) :

```
/*The initial array : I chose this one as it is simpler than the one in the question and I find it better for illustration purposes*/
/*Considering the question, we will only get the values ended by 0 (first value of each subarray )*/
$arrays = [['00','01'],['10','11'],['20','11']];

/*Initialisation of the result array*/
$indexes = [];

/*We are going to use the new syntax for list() function introduced in php 7.1  (See the credits link for list() function usage examples )*/

/* We pull the first value (index 0) of each subarray that we store in the result array ($indexes) */

foreach($arrays as $array){ 
    list('0'=>$indexes[]) = $array; 
}

var_dump($indexes); // ['00','10','20']
```

Credits : [The list function & practical uses of array destructuring in PHP](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/the-list-function-and-practical-uses-of-array-destructuring-in-php)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/jHN0p)

Comment: I noticed my answer has been downvoted and I would want to know what I missed ...

Comment: After browsing some downvoted answers, I found that my above answer should include more explanations. I neglected doing that because I provided a link to the original article. However, I will try to give better answers with more explanations in the future.  I would be glad to know more about anything I did wrong either you downvoted or not.